# Why am I getting an error with my '2014' date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Why am I getting an error with my `'2014'` date?

```
Some Select Clause
Some Where Clause
AND TRAN_DT DATE BETWEEN '2014/04/01' AND'2014/04/30'
```

Comment: What gives you `show datestyle;`

Comment: @Bai; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an extra unneeded word. You have `TRAN_DT DATE` with a space in the middle. Use

```
AND TRAN_DT BETWEEN '2014/04/01' AND'2014/04/30' -- if column is [TRAN_DT]
```

or

```
AND [TRAN_DT DATE] BETWEEN '2014/04/01' AND'2014/04/30' -- if column is [TRAN_DT DATE]
```